# Full text catalog population always in progress, never actually populated

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-indexing

I have created a full text index on my dev server on a view that returns few rows.

The population schedule is currently set to run once a day.

However the full text index is returning no results as though it is not populated.

If I run *SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('My Catalog', 'PopulateStatus')*, the result is always **1**, indicating that a full population is in progress. It has been like this for hours.

If I run *ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON myView START FULL POPULATION*, I receive an error message saying that a population is in progress.

I couldn't take the database offline because of this population so I had to restart the whole server.

I'm using SQL 2005 SP3.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and moved the whole database over to an SQL 2008 server - the problem no longer occurs.
Must be something wrong with SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL server are you running?

This hot fix applies to 2005 SP1, where full text searches take a long time to populate on an indexed view. (Note this is fixed in SP2)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928537

If that doesn't help post some more details about your environment, table size etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply - its SQL 2005 SP 3 (9.0.4035). The view is small (less than 20 rows) as this is only a dev server.

Comment: If you duplicate the table, but with no data, relationships, PK or indexes does it do the same thing?  If its now fast try adding the data (still without any indexes etc) and see if it still runs fast.  Then we'll see what else can be thought of.